# Postgresql support which type of sanitization processes?

Tags: postgresql

If we just drop the database from PostgreSQL then can we say that data deleted permanently, and securely?

How can we follow industry-standard sanitization processes, e.g., NIST 800-88 with postgresql ?

Comment: The data is deleted using the filsystem's delete function. I would assume that it's not overwritten and could theoretically be restored using forensic tools. This also depends a bit on the filsystem being used I guess.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for that built into PostgreSQL, since that belongs to the physical properties of the file system, and PostgreSQL uses the kernel's file system API and has no knowledge about the file system's inner workings.

Even if PostgreSQL went as far as overwriting files with random data before deleting them (which it doesn't), that wouldn't achieve anything on a copy-on-write file system after a snapshot has been taken.

You are approaching this on the wrong layer. This requirement has to be handled on the file system level.

Comment: Thank  you for answer.
So how can we  erases files from magnetic memory and thereby making it impossible to recover deleted files or directory content.

I mean after dropdb which actions have required?
do you know?

Comment: After `dropdb` that is almost impossible, because that only removes some files from the cluster. And the WAL cannot be removed. You keep every database in its own cluster on its own file system, and to remove it you write random noise over the physical devices behind the file system.